# copy data to new year in sql

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I'm working on an old asp app and going to copy data of puplic holiday to new year in the same table. This code below insert Null to my table. I think we should use a temp table but don't know how -I'm a new bie.
Here my code:

```
<!-- #include file="../IncludeFile/phuongvh_vn.inc" -->
<!-- #include file="../IncludeFile/connection.inc" -->
<!-- #include file="../IncludeFile/changeformat.txt" -->
<%
if session("Login")<>"YES" then
    Response.Redirect "../login.asp"
end if
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Move Holiday Information</title>
</head>
<%

    MySql = "Select * From tblHolidayTF Where Year(Holdate)=YEAR(GETDATE())"
    rs.Open MySql, Conn, 2, 2

%>
<BODY bgcolor="#fef9f3" text=#8b0000 aLink=#dc143c link=#1e90ff vLink=#1e90ff>
<%  
 if not rs.eof then
rs.AddNew

  rs("OfficeCode")=rs("OfficeCode")
  rs("Descript")=rs("Descript") 
  rs("Days")=rs("Days")
  rs("WorkHour")=rs("WorkHour")
rs("HolDate")=dateadd("yyyy",1,GETDATE())
//rs("HolDate")=GETDATE()


  rs("EndDate")=rs("EndDate")               
  if request("chkMemoSent")="on" then
        rs("MemoSent")=true
    else
        rs("MemoSent")=false
    end if
rs("Significance")=rs("Significance")   
  rs.Update
end if
%>
<center>
Holiday
<% if HolID<>"" then %> added
<% else %> updated
<% end if %> successfully... <br>
If this window is not going to close automatically in 5 seconds, please <br>
<a href="javascript:window.opener.location.reload();window.close();">Click here</a> to return...
<script>
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- #include file="../IncludeFile/disconnection.inc" -->
```

Comment: Not much info on what actually goes wrong: is a record inserted into the database or not? Is this record empty (null)? Please check if your code hits the 'if not rs.eof' part. Besides that: I also expect a loop or is there only 1 holiday per year? And you fill "HolDate" with the current date, so if you run this script today, then Christmas could be on 12/23/2015 next year :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes a record Inserted with <Null> value for any collum except the first collum -auto increase- this is the key collum. Because of null value _ I've just try change 'Holdate" like that - but null value still there (NULL instead of 12/23/2015 ). There is many Holiday but I can't figure out how to insert one byone record, May be we have to use rs.First and rs. Next but we should at leat insert one record successfully.

Comment: When you use `rs.AddNew` you are adding a new row (obviously :) ) to the recordset., being a new row, none of those fields will have any values. That is why they are inserting nulls when you do `rs("Descript")=rs("Descript")` etc. And for the `HolDate` field, use `date()` instead of `getdate()` and you should get the current date inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same recordset (Rs) for this. By doing an .AddNew, the new record will be the current record in you recordset(like SearchAndResQ already mentioned).

Create a second record set to create the new record:

```
MySql = "Select OfficeCode, Descript From tblHolidayTF Where Year(Holdate)=YEAR(GETDATE())"

Rs.Open MySql, Conn, 2, 2

If Not Rs.EOF Then
    Dim RsNew: Set RsNew = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    RsNew.Open "tblHolidayTF", Conn, 2, 2
    RsNew.AddNew
    RsNew("OfficeCode") = Rs("OfficeCode")
    RsNew("Descript") = Rs("Descript")
    RsNew.Update
    RsNew.Close
End If
```

or (better?), copy the values of your Rs to an array, close the recordset and create a new record. In that case you need to specify the columns in your query to know the sequence.

```
MySql = "Select OfficeCode, Descript From tblHolidayTF Where Year(Holdate)=YEAR(GETDATE())"

Rs.Open MySql, Conn, 2, 2

If Not Rs.EOF Then
   Dim OldData: OldData = Rs.GetRows()

   Rs.AddNew
   Rs("OfficeCode") = OldData(0,0)
   Rs("Descript") = OldData(1,0)
   Rs.Update
End If
```